# Last catch-all ModRewrite takes precedent over previous rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some difficulty with my `.htaccess` file which I cannot seem to understand. According to the [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) it should be working as I expect, however it is not. My first two rules only work when my last rule is commented out. Once I add the last rule it appears as though the first two rules no longer matter. Please advise. (I am aware that an unversioned api endpoint is ill-advised but I need it for compatibility for now.)

```
RewriteRule beta api.v2.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule v1/(.*)$ api.v1.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
#current default api version
RewriteRule (.*)$ api.v1.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

With this htaccess `domain.dev/beta/endpoint` will go to `api.v1.php` instead of `api.v2.php` (using [Slim](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-URL-Rewriting)) however once the last line is removed it goes to v2 as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your posted htaccess it seems the rewrite goes: beta -> api.v2.php -> api.v1.php

Suggestion: put conditions on rewrite rules, and explicitly check for api.v2.php on the last one

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/beta
RewriteRule beta api.v2.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/v1
RewriteRule v1\/(.*)$ /api.v1.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

# make sure not to rewrite valid api requests (api.v2.php) to default version
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/api
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.v1.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Awesome! I don't know why this was needed as I would have thought the RewriteRules in themselves would have done this properly, but it now works properly. I made some minor edits to your code to fix a few things and make it forward-looking